# How to get current page on Settings charm opened

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime

How to get current page or frame on Settings_CommandsRequested?
I want to navigate from settings pane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current `Frame` is the one you are showing so you get to define how you access it. You can save the instance reference as a static field on the App class or use an IoC container to access it. The most simple way to do it is to make following updates to your App class:

```
sealed partial class App : Application
{
    public static Frame RootFrame { get; private set; }

    ...

    protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
    {
        Frame rootFrame = this.RootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

        // Do not repeat app initialization when the Window already has content,
        // just ensure that the window is active
        if (rootFrame == null)
        {
            // Create a Frame to act as the navigation context and navigate to the first page
            rootFrame = this.RootFrame = new Frame();
            ...
```

Then you can simply call `App.RootFrame` to get your frame.

Comment: Thanks,  it didn't worked OnLaunched - it returs null object. But on Settings_CommandsRequested it is useful "Window.Current.Content as Frame". Thank you again, I got the idea how to get current Frame.

Comment: Right, I should have added a few more lines, let me edit the answer.